# I want to receive the tweets of everyone I follow as emails. How do I configure that?

Tags: twitter, email

I suspect this might require a 3rd party application.

There is no way that I would want SMS notifications to my phone (which is almost what I'm looking for).

And if I could get emails just for particular users that would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [TweetyMail.com](http://tweetymail.com/). From their FAQ:

> tweetymail is a complete email interface to Twitter.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: It's pretty logical to assume that it does what the question asks.

Comment: The answer is TweetyMail.com, which has a long list of features for sending email to twitter and receiving information back from twitter as an email.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a RSS-to-email gateway like [feedmyinbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/) on the RSS feed for the twitter timeline in question.